# HttpClient 4.5.2 Proxy setting

Tags: java, web-services, proxy, spring-batch, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to call third party web service via proxy.

I only have information below:
-  Third party https IP & Port
-  Proxy http IP & Port

May I know I need credential : username & Password for the Proxy?

Part of my code below:-

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort);
    DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new
    DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
    .build();

        RequestConfig config =RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy).build();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(queryUrl);
            httppost.setConfig(config);

CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

**Unfortunately, Proxy server reponse me "Access denied. Authentication is required."**

Any idea for this problem?